# HMS cant get PushToken in Flutter

Tags: flutter, huawei-mobile-services

I have no idea what happened, as it doesn't return anything after these logs, and I can never get the Token for Push kit, did enable auto init in AndroidManifest.

I am using Flutter 3.0.4, dart 2.17.5, devtools 2.12.2, stable channel. I am using P40 Pro, with EMUI 11.0.0.203.

Huawei SDK
Push kit is 6.3.0+304
com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.4.2.301

Can anyone please help?

Here are the related logs.

```
HMSSDK_HmsClient(11995): receive msg status_code:0, error_code:0, api_name:push.gettoken, app_id:101874381|, pkg_name:com.app.android, session_id:*, transaction_id:101874381ttoken20220711125321625496651, resolution:null
HMSSDK_TaskApiCall(11995): doExecute, uri:push.gettoken, errorCode:0, transactionId:101874381ttoken20220711125321625496651
HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager(11995): Enter getHMSPackageNameForMultiService
I/HMSSDK_RequestManager(11995): removeReqByTransId
D/HMSLogger(11995): singleEventMap -> {apiName=getToken, package=com.app.android, cpAppVersion=5.0.0, version=6.1.0.300, platform=Flutter, result=0, costTime=135, service=Cross-Platform, kit=Push, appid=101874381, model=HWELS, networkType=WIFI, callTime=1657515201747}
```

Comment: Can you provide the complete log info for us to check?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Seems i can't paste the whole thing here, so i did put up a ticket in developer console.

But i did follow the doc on how to implement, but still it never returns the Token through the stream, is there any reason may trigger this to happened

Comment: According to the tickets logs, you are trying to call firebase messaging getToken, and Firebase messaging will not work in HMS device.